# Delete one of the question_id from following schema

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have a following schema and I want to delete one of the `question_id` from following schema:

[image]

I used following query:

```
db.getCollection('test').update(
    { },
    { $pull: { sections:{ questions_ids: "SzaGcEr8oZ7fEsrC3} } }
)
```

But this query is not updating anything and when I used `multi:true` then it is deleting whole section. Please update me where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 db.getCollection('test').update(
     { },
    { $pull: { sections:{ questions_ids: ["SzaGcEr8oZ7fEsrC3"]} } }
    )
```

Comment: I tried but still its not working. It says "Updated 1 existing record(s) in 1ms" but when I checked still that question_id is present.

Comment: db.getCollection('test').update(
     { },
    { $pull: { sections:{ questions_ids: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId("SzaGcEr8oZ7fEsrC3")} } }
    )